# Wait for functions in for loop to finish

Tags: javascript, node.js, for-loop

I have a for loop in NodeJS. Inside the loop is a function that gets data from a database.

```
var player2.schedule = {
  opponent: //string
  datetime: //date object
}

var schedule = "";

for (i=0; i<player2.schedule.length; i++) { 
  User.findOne({ id: player2.schedule[i].opponent }.select("name").exec(function(err, opponent) {
    schedule += opponent.name;
  });
}
```

The loop adds to a variable `schedule` with the results from the database call each time the loop goes round.

Now my problem is if I have code after the for loop that relies on this `schedule` variable, it can't. Because the variable is updated in the callback function from the database call, any code after the for loop happens asynchronously, so the variable hasn't been updated in time.

How can I make sure the next batch of code waits for the for loop and callbacks to finish first?

Comment: You can use https://github.com/caolan/async library...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple example using [`async`](https://github.com/caolan/async):

```
var async = require('async');

async.each(player2.schedule, function(item, cb) {
  User.findOne({ id: item.opponent })
      .select("name")
      .exec(function(err, opponent) {
    if (err)
      return cb(err);
    schedule += opponent.name;
    cb();
  });
}, function(err) {
  if (err)
    throw err;
  console.log('All done');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use async library function whilst() to wait for all queries to finish:

```
var async = require('async');
var i = 0;
var len = player2.schedule.length;
async.whilst(
  function () { return i < len; },
  function (callback) {
    User.findOne({ id:player2.schedule[i].opponent}.select("name").exec(function(err, opponent) {
      schedule += opponent.name;
      i++;
      callback(null);   // assume no error (null)
    });
  },
  function (err) {
    // this function is executed after all queries are done
    // schedule now has everything from the loop
  } 
);
```